# VBA Excel run time error 424

Tags: vba, excel

I know that this is a very common question asked in this forum and other forums but the answers given couldn't help me so I am asking it again.

I am trying to create a quiz with Excel and for that I am adding a checkbox to check to validate the choice and see the answer. The problem is that I am having this VBA run-time error ' object required' and I cannot work it out.

Here is the VBA code I am executing

```
Sub affichageQuestion()

    Dim xlw As Workbook    
    Set xlw = Workbooks("quiz.xlsm")

    xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(2).Visible = msoTrue

    xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3") = xlw.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value
    xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8") = xlw.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
    xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10") = xlw.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").Value
    xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B12") = xlw.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Value
    xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B14") = xlw.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5").Value

    If (validate.Value = -1) Then
        If (xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3").Value = 2) Then
            xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(2).Visible = msoTrue
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

With the Step into function I located the error on this line

```
If (validate.Value = -1) Then
```

But I am enable to find a solution.
If someone could answer me as soon as possible I'll be really glade, because my internship responsible is waiting for the quiz

Comment: What is `validate` in your code?

Comment: is `validate` a forms checkbox or ActiveX?

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox is directly on your worksheet then try:

```
If xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").validate.Value = False Then
```